# How can I get Wikipedia embedded audio and video to play back in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, video, quicktime

What is required to get the embedded Ogg Vorbis/Theora media on Wikipedia to play back natively in Safari, assuming a clean, up-to-date OS X install?

The Wikipedia page for [Beethoven's Piano Sonata No. 14](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piano_Sonata_No._14_(Beethoven)) can be used as an example. In Chrome, this page renders the following infobox:

[image: Chrome screenshot]

In Safari, this same excerpt renders as following:

[image: Safari screenshot]

Comment: Could you provide an example Wikipedia page, please?

Comment: @MicahHummert Done!

Comment: You wouldn't have any extensions installed that would interfere with it, would you? You can check under `Safari > Preferences... > Extensions` and look at the lefthand column. I'm asking because Safari should be able to play those files already - as long as you have iTunes installed.

Comment: Doesn't this site tell you what you need for that?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Media_help_(audio_and_video)

Comment: I _did_ write this question over a year ago, and at that time the solutions in the Wikipedia help document did not work (they suggested obsolete software). I will try again, but does anyone actually have this working already?

Comment: The documentation offers three options, only one of which suggests in-browser playback through installing a codec component. Upon doing so, OGG files will play back in QT 7, and the web players will display, but browser playback still won't work.

Comment: Yes, that's what I have since years. The most simple solution: Open page in Firefox (via enabled Developer Menu), firefox can play back Ogg.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia is not directly using the HTML5 audio tag (which it should be) and is not supporting media in Safari at this time (likely due to it's lack of popularity) so It's recommended to use Chrome (which is basically safari that Google improved upon) or Firefox.

example page:
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Libre_music

```
document.querySelectorAll('audio').length
0
```

The "compatibility" layer (mw.PopUpMediaTransform) they are trying to use makes the audio tag after you click play but in safari it tries some java applet that breaks.